# Why "powers and duties of a referee" is put on hold as too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Why [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/13011/10760) question is put on hold as too broad ?

I think it is well defined and has a proper answer.

I don't think this question has too many possible answers or too long answers.

**What are the general reasons to put a question on hold as too broad ?**

Comment: Did you read the Rules of the Game before posting the question? If so, what wasn't clear in the Rules?

Comment: "[Have you thoroughly searched for an answer *before* asking your question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?"

Comment: I searched for powers of a referee, and found some answers , but couldn't find laws by fifa.That was the reason I added **defined in the football laws** in my question.

Comment: I searched "[football laws powers and duties](https://www.google.com/search?q=football+laws+powers+and+duties)" on Google, and was able to find them "defined in the football laws" in the second result, with highlights in the first result. That said, your question doesn't merit "too broad" but arguably "low effort," but that's neither here or there, but my personal opinion (which I know is shared).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions that are "low effort" should not be closed as "too broad", nor as any other particular close reason, unless that reason applies.  "Too broad" is not a standin for "low effort".

Low effort questions should be downvoted, and commented as to what would improve them.  This question qualifies for that, I think.  I've cast a reopen vote and a downvote.

---

That said, I have been in the past, and am still, in favor of an off topic close reason along the lines of "research request", for things like this.  But realistically this isn't all that bad of an question/answer to have on this site, in itself; having a question that has the powers and duties of referees in FIFA laws can be useful for close-as-dup for questions relating to them in the future.

Comment: +1 for "too broad is not a stand in for low effort."

Answer (score 0):

> What are the general reasons to put a question on hold as too broad?

In basic terms, general reasons are posted in our [help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> These are the categories of questions that may be closed by the
>   community:
>
> - **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our
>     format
>
>   > There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   >     too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer
>   >     set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.